# .htaccess redirect if URL contains date

Tags: regex, .htaccess

We are in the process of moving a site to a new domain name. We are redirecting the original domain to a new site. URLs for the old site contain dates (YYYY/MM/DD) while the URLs for the site do not. Therefore, I would like to redirect any URL request that contains a date to the new domain name. What is the correct function to use, and the correct regular expression, in order to do this in the .htaccess file?

The URLs with dates are formed this way:

```
http://ourwebsite.com/2018/02/20/some-page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule in site root .htaccess file on your old host:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/.*)$ http://newsite/$1
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a step in the right direction. I would like to construct the redirect URL such that it contains the original path. For example, this: `http://oldsite/2018/02/20/some-page` should go to `http://newsite/2018/02/20/some-page`.